# Slice a list to max string size

Tags: python

I have a max length of a list item that I need to enforce. How would I accomplish the following:

```
MAX_LENGTH = 13
>>> str(["hello","david"])[:MAX_LENGTH]
"['hello', 'da"

==> ["hello", "da"]
```

I was thinking using `ast.literal_eval`, but was wondering what might be recommended here.

Comment: Just to make sure - you want the constraint applied to each item?

Comment: Nope, the entire length of the list (in my actual problem it is not to exceed 10KB).

Comment: So you want to effectively concatenate all the list items, splice the string (`[:MAX_LENGTH]`), and turn it into a list (making sure to separate the elements properly)?

Comment: I would caution against this. There has to be safer things to do than this. At the very least you should never be splitting elements in half.

Comment: Could you please clarify your example: do you want MAX_LENGTH of the string representation of your list of MAX_LENGTH of the all the strings concatenated? May be the better is to explain what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would caution against this. There has to be safer things to do than this. At the very least you should never be splitting elements in half. For instance:

```
import sys

overrun = []

data = ["Hello,"] + ( ["buffer"] * 80 )
maxsize = 800

# sys.getsizeof(data) is now 840 in my implementation.

while True:
    while sys.getsizeof(data) > maxsize:
        overrun.append(data.pop())
    do_something_with(data)
    if overrun:
        data, overrun = overrun, []
    else:
        break
```

Comment: thanks for this answer. Though it seems I needed to do `sys.getsizeof(str(data))` for it to accurately return the size.

Comment: @David542 that's probably true if you're sending it over the wire as a string. You definitely should check the size of your payload, not its underlying data!! Glad I could help

Comment: @David542: `sys.getsizeof` reports interpreter details of size (including stuff like the overhead involved in the common `PyObject` header and stuff, the internal fixed width encoding of the `str`, etc.), not how much space it would actually take up in a file or on the wire. If you want wire size, you'd want to encode (to UTF-8 or whatever character encoding the protocol uses), and check the `len` of the resulting `bytes` object which is how many real bytes would be sent, `sys.getsizeof` really only tells you (sort of) how much memory it occupies in the Python interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified version of @AdamSmith's answer which I ended up using:

```
import sys
from copy import copy

def limit_list_size(ls, maxsize=800):
    data = copy(ls)
    while (sys.getsizeof(str(data)) > maxsize):
        if not data: break
        data.pop()
    return data
```

Note that this will not split mid-word. And because this is returning a copy of the data, the user can see which items were excluded in the output. For example:

```
old_ls = [...]
new_ls = limit_list_size(old_ls)
overflow_ls = list(set(old_ls) - set(new_ls))
```

Comment: As long as you're aware that you're losing data here. I'm not sure what you're doing with this, but it seems surprising that if I want to send a too-long list, it only sends the first `N` elements and ignores the rest!

Comment: @AdamSmith right, your answer is more complete and accounts for the overflow, etc. The above was a quick way for me to get it functionally working in the script.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `MAX_LENGTH` of your strings concatenated, you could do it with a loop pretty simply, using something like this:

```
 def truncateStringList(myArray)

    currentLength = 0
    result = []

    for string in myArray:
        if (currentLength + len(string)) > MAX_LENGTH:
            result.append(string[:len(string) + currentLength - MAX_LENGTH])
            return result
        else:
            result.append(string)
    return result
```

If you want it of the string representation, you are effectively adding 2 chars at the beginning of each element, `['` or `'`, and two at the end, `',` or `']`, so add 2 to current length before and after each element in the loop:

```
    for string in myArray:
        currentLength += 2
        if (currentLength + len(string)) > MAX_LENGTH:
            result.append(string[:len(string) + currentLength - MAX_LENGTH])
            return result
        else:
            result.append(string)
        currentLength += 2
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

with loops:

```
max = 11
mylist = ['awdawdwad', 'uppps']
newlist = ','.join(mylist)
print mylist
c= [x for x in newlist if not x==',']
if len(c)>max:
    newlist= list(newlist)
    newlist.reverse()
    for x in range(len(c)-max):
        if newlist[0]==',':
            del newlist[0]
            del newlist[0] # delete two times
        else:
            del newlist[0]
        while newlist[0]==',':
            del newlist[0]
newlist.reverse()
cappedlist =  ''.join(newlist).split(',')
print cappedlist
```